# What is the biomedical term for what I can name "dissolvable heaps" that a masseuse can most often dissolve in about 2-3 minutes of focused massaging?

Tags: acidic

What is the biomedical term for what I can name "dissolvable heaps" that a masseuse can most often dissolve in about 2-3 minutes of focused massaging?

A certain masseuse told me something like that these "heaps" are made of acids and/or salts (I don't have a personal exact recollection of what was said). I hope it has a biomedical English name so I could easily search data on this on the web so if you know the name please tell me the name.

Comment: I've not heard of lumps of salts in the skin. Usually those "heaps" are just small muscle knots.

Comment: @JohnP I mean to heaps that appear In different places in different times; mostly in the back; I think these are totally muscle related but not necessarily muscle knots (but I might be wrong about that).